# How to run command line Node as `type: module` while still run `npm` scripts regularly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, node-modules

I am developing some Node code that runs on the browser.  `npm start` and `npm test` work well.

Some of the same code can be run on the command line.  If I simply run `node myscript.js`, I get errors, because then Node wants it to be a CommonJS module, not an ECMAScript module.  I can solve this by adding a `"type": "module"` line to the parent `package.json`.  But this breaks the `npm start` and `npm test`, which don't support that line in the package.json module.

I tried creating a second `package.json` in the `scripting/` folder (where `myscript.js` is), but Node seems to ignore it.

How can I tell Node to run the `myscript.js` as an ECMAScript but still allow `npm start` and `npm test` to work.

I am running Node v12.  It's a restricted development environment, so upgrading Node would be difficult, but perhaps not impossible.  I do not know if this is related.